# cannot connect mysql with android in wampserver localhost using emulator

Tags: php, android, mysql

my database name is mobildb and it contain a table androidlogin .It contains id integer
  autoincrement primary key,user text,password text as its field.my table contains some login
 detail.iwant to check the username and password entered in android form with the data in table.my
 php file name is login.php saved in wamp/www/.I dont know to give the http link.I tested
  this code with my lap ipaddress,127.0.0.1 , 10.0.2.2  , 12.34.56.78:80  ,  0.0.0.0:80
  ,127.0.0.1:80    ,10.0.2.2:80.can help me please?
  my php file is

```
     <?php
     $dbhost="localhost";
     $db="mobiledb";
     $pass="";
     $dbuser="root";
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mobiledb") or die("connection error");
     //mysqli_select_db($con,"mobiledb") or die("database not exists");
     $username=$_POST["username"];
     $password=$_POST["password"];
     $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from androidlogin where user='$username' AND 
                                                    password='$password'");
     $num=mysqli_num_rows($query);
     if($num==1){
     while($list=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){
     $output=$list;}
     echo json_encode($output);
      }
     mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
```

my activity is contain only 2 edittext for username and password.a button for login

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MyActivity">


 <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtuser"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pswd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtuser"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_below="@id/pswd"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="btnClick" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

my only class file is

```
 package com.example.iyas.loginapp;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


  public class MyActivity extends Activity {
String username,password;
EditText user;
EditText pass;
Button btn;
HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
HttpResponse httpresponse;
HttpEntity entity;


ArrayList namevaluepairs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    initialise();
 }
 private void initialise()
 {
    user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pswd);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

 }
 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is){
 BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  String line=null;
 try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line + "\n");
   }
 } catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
       try{
           is.close();
          }catch(IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();         }
   }return sb.toString();

   }

 public void btnClick(View v)
  {
 httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
 httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/login.php");
 username=user.getText().toString();
 password=pass.getText().toString();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"before try",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 try{
     namevaluepairs=new ArrayList();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"after try",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
     namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"after name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
     httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);
     if(httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
         entity=httpresponse.getEntity();
         if(entity!=null){
             InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
            JSONObject jsonresponse=new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
             String retUser= jsonresponse.getString("user");
             String retPass=jsonresponse.getString("password");
             if(username.equals(retUser)&&password.equals(retPass)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"invalid login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
         }
     }
     }catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();


     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"connection error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} 
    catch(JSONException e)
    {  e.printStackTrace(); 

  }
  }

 }
```

manifest file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.iyas.loginapp" >

 <application 
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 </manifest>


 my error in logcat after login button clicks:


10-20 04:22:05.593    7672-7672/com.example.iyas.loginapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
               Process: com.example.iyas.loginapp, PID: 7672
             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3970)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4598)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19268)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:738)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

and app stops unfortunately

Comment: put your code of calling web inside thread

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure you have Internet Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Then put any long operation inside thread , calling web method is long operation so put it inside Thread

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Your web calling goes here


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});




thread.start();
```

this will work

but also you can try to add this code to your class , to make sure every thing will be just fine

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: i tried with thread.there is no error.But the app cannot connect to database.it doesn't retrieve anything.can anyone help

Comment: write your local server address in your browser and make sure its reachable first

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask to call network related request. Make request in doInBackground method of AsyncTask. If you do network related requests on main thread then NetworkOnMainThreadException exception is thrown